# Sketch Widget Snapping, how to access the snapped point's object? (ArcGIS API for JS)

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I'm using the ArcGIS API Sketch Widget for an application and it has a Point graphics layer as the feature source layer, which the Sketch Widget uses to snap to when hovering around the map. I need to grab the coordinates of the point being snapped to. Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

In the code snippet, click the "Draw Point" button in the top-right of the map. Cursor should change to crosshairs. When you move the cursor around the map, you can see the lat/long values on the left. When the cursor is close enough to snap to the black point, the point turns orange. While the point is orange, you can see that the lat/long values continue to change as you move around the point, but I need to make it to where if the Sketch tool has snapped to a point, it will grab that point's coordinates.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Sketch widget | Sample | ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript 4.26</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #hover-box{
      background-color: white;
      left: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 200px;
      top: 100px;     
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    #draw-btn{
      height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/"></script>
  <script>
    require([
      "esri/widgets/Sketch",
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/geometry/geometryEngine"
    ], (Sketch, Map, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, MapView, esriGeometryEngine) => {
      let drawingActive = false;
      let xElement = document.getElementById("hover-x");
      let yElement = document.getElementById("hover-y");
  
      const drawLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
      const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
      
      const map = new Map({
        basemap: "topo-vector",
        layers: [drawLayer, graphicsLayer]
      });

      const view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        zoom: 15,
        center: [-118.80657463861, 34.0005930608889]
      });
         
      const point = { //Create a point
        type: "point",
        longitude: -118.80657463861,
        latitude: 34.0005930608889
      };
  
      const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
        geometry: point,
      });
      graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);   
  
      let sketch;
      view.when(() => {
        sketch = new Sketch({
          layer: drawLayer,
          view: view,
          creationMode: "single",
          visibleElements: {
            createTools: {
              point: true,
              polyline: false,
              polygon: false,
              rectangle: false,
              circle: false,
            },
          settingsMenu: false,
          undoRedoMenu: false,
          selectionTools: {
            'rectangle-selection': false,
            'lasso-selection': false,
          }
         },
          snappingOptions: {
            enabled: true,
            distance: 200,
            featureSources: [{enabled: true, layer: graphicsLayer}]
          }
        });
        
        sketch.on('create', () => {
          drawingActive = false;
          sketch.cancel();
        })
        
        view.ui.add(document.getElementById('draw-btn'), "top-right");
        setUpSnappingTooltip();
      });
  
     const element = document.getElementById("draw-btn");
     element.addEventListener("click", addPoint);
  
     function addPoint(){
       if (drawingActive) sketch.cancel();
       else {
         drawingActive = true;
         sketch.create("point");
       }
     }
  
      function setUpSnappingTooltip() {
        view.on('pointer-move', (event) => {
          snappingTooltip(event);
        })
      }
  
      async function snappingTooltip(event) {
        // Run only when drawing is active
        if (drawingActive) {
          const point = view.toMap(event);
          xElement.innerHTML = `Long: ${point.longitude}`
          yElement.innerHTML = `Lat: ${point.latitude}`
        }
      }
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  <button id="draw-btn">Draw Point</button>
  <div id="hover-box">
    <b>Map hover lat/long</b>
    <p id="hover-y">Lat: </p>
    <p id="hover-x">Long: </p>   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the black point geometry. That is the way snap works, and your code is working properly. If you compare the coordinates of the pointer and the sketched geometry you will see they differ (unless the pointer is on top of the black point).

(This actually should be a comment but I wanted to add a small change to your code so you can check it.)

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Get XY of Snapped Point</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #hover-box {
            background-color: white;
            left: 15px;
            position: absolute;
            min-width: 250px;
            top: 100px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #draw-btn {
            height: 50px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "esri/widgets/Sketch",
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/Graphic",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
            "esri/views/MapView",
            "esri/geometry/geometryEngine"
        ], (Sketch, Map, Graphic, FeatureLayer, GraphicsLayer, MapView, esriGeometryEngine) => {
            let drawingActive = false;
            const xElement = document.getElementById("hover-x");
            const yElement = document.getElementById("hover-y");
            const xSnap = document.getElementById("snap-x");
            const ySnap = document.getElementById("snap-y");

            const point = { //Create a point
                type: "point",
                longitude: -118.80657463861,
                latitude: 34.0005930608889
            };

            const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
                geometry: point,
                attributes: {OBJECTID: 1}
            });
            const drawLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
            const pointLayer = new FeatureLayer({
                source: [pointGraphic],
                objectIdField: "OBJECTID"
            });

            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "topo-vector",
                layers: [drawLayer, pointLayer]
            });
            const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
                zoom: 15,
                center: [-118.80657463861, 34.0005930608889]
            });

            view.whenLayerView(pointLayer).then(function(layerView){
                layerView.watch("updating", function(value){
                    if (value) {
                        return;
                    }
                    const sketch = new Sketch({
                        layer: drawLayer,
                        view: view,
                        creationMode: "single",
                        visibleElements: {
                            createTools: {
                                point: true,
                                polyline: false,
                                polygon: false,
                                rectangle: false,
                                circle: false,
                            },
                            settingsMenu: false,
                            undoRedoMenu: false,
                            selectionTools: {
                                'rectangle-selection': false,
                                'lasso-selection': false,
                            }
                        },
                        snappingOptions: {
                            enabled: true,
                            distance: 200,
                            featureSources: [{ enabled: true, layer: pointLayer }]
                        }
                    });

                    sketch.on('create', (event) => {
                        if (event.state === "complete") {
                            console.log(event.graphic.geometry.toJSON());
                            drawingActive = false;
                            sketch.cancel();
                        }
                    })

                    function setUpSnappingTooltip() {
                        view.on('pointer-move', (event) => {
                            const point = view.toMap(event);
                            if (drawingActive) {
                                xElement.innerHTML = `${point.x}`;
                                yElement.innerHTML = `${point.y}`;
                                layerView.queryFeatures({
                                    geometry: point,
                                    distance: 200 * view.resolution, // same as snap option
                                    spatialRelationship: "intersects",
                                    returnGeometry: true
                                }).then(response => {
                                    if (response.features.length > 0) {
                                        xSnap.innerHTML = `${response.features[0].geometry.x}`;
                                        ySnap.innerHTML = `${response.features[0].geometry.y}`;
                                    } else {
                                        xSnap.innerHTML = "";
                                        ySnap.innerHTML = "";
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    view.ui.add(document.getElementById('draw-btn'), "top-right");
                    setUpSnappingTooltip();

                    function addPoint() {
                        if (drawingActive) sketch.cancel();
                        else {
                            drawingActive = true;
                            sketch.create("point");
                        }
                    }
                    const element = document.getElementById("draw-btn");
                    element.addEventListener("click", addPoint);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
        <button id="draw-btn">Draw Point</button>
        <div id="hover-box">
            <b>Map hover lat/long</b></br>
            Hover Y: <span id="hover-y"></span><br>
            Hover X: <span id="hover-x"></span><br>
            Snap Y: <span id="snap-y"></span><br>
            Snap X: <span id="snap-x"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I see what you mean. I did not find in the docs a way to get the snap point using the snap tool, so I implement a simple query on the view layer using the same distance that the snap. Now, if there is a way that the snap tool give the snap point, it is obviously a better solution. (I have updated the snippet)

Comment: Yes, I need to get the snapped point's geometry, but it needs to be in real time while the user is hovering around on the map. In reality, there will be hundreds of points to snap to, so the user wants to be able to see the coordinates of the snapping points to help them determine where they want to place the new point.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a possible solution